Can't use Redis with Laravel
I'm trying to connect to a Redis server I have installed on my local server, from a Laravel app (my final goal is to produce Prometheus metrics).
Redis is alive and kicking (bind on 127.0.0.1 only, without authentication):
# systemctl status redis
[sudo] password for devel: 
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-05-29 11:14:32 CEST; 1h 18min ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
   Main PID: 967352 (redis-server)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 18663)
     Memory: 5.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
             └─967352 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
May 29 11:14:32 Ubuntu-2004-services2 systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
May 29 11:14:32 Ubuntu-2004-services2 systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.

File .env contains (among other values):
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

The first endpoint I'm setting up ('/metrics') calls the method \Prometheus\CollectorRegistry::getDefault()->getOrRegisterCounter('', 'some_quick_counter', 'just a quick measurement')->inc();
The error I keep getting in the logs is:
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::connect()"

And effectively file /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Redis.php does not contain a connect() method...
If it can help, I'm on:

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
php 8.0.2
laravel/framework 9.19
predis 2.2

Any clues?

Don't believe you will find that method in the Facade. What does redis-cli tell you when you try to connect? [https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/connect/]

Why do you think there is such a method? The documentation doesn't mention it. Maybe you've aliased the wrong class?

@Andreas:
The command redis-cli gets me: "127.0.0.1:6379>". Asking for "help", I get: "redis-cli 5.0.7"

@miken32: I'm not using `connect() method myself... It's the error I get in the Laravel logs when I request the test endpoint...

I see, hard to tell without any stack trace. Have you looked at that source file? Is it intentionally calling Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::connect() or is it perhaps expecting that \Redis::connect() will exist from some extension or other that you haven't installed?

@miken32: I suppose it was expecting that \Redis::connect() will exist from predis extension, that I did not install... No I did install it, and the error is changed: 'Class "Redis" not found" on line 23 of file /var/www/services/api-ski-test/app/Providers/PrometheusServiceProvider.php'. I am now following https://medium.com/@cgtysylr/creating-prometheus-metrics-in-laravel-433f704cbf4 tutorial...

It is necessary to correctly initialize the CollectorRegistry, indicating to it which connection to use. That's what ServiceProvider is for.
In AppServiceProvider::register() you need to configure Redis adapter like this
public function register(): void
{
  $this->app->singleton(CollectorRegistry::class, static function () {
        $config = config('database.redis.default');
        $redis = new \Prometheus\Storage\Redis([
            'host'         => $config['host'],
            'port'         => (int) $config['port'],
            'password'     => $config['password'],
            'read_timeout' => (string) ($config['read_timeout'] ?? '1'),
        ]);
    
        return new CollectorRegistry($redis);
    });
}

And than get CollectorRegistry from container:
app(CollectorRegistry::class)->getOrRegisterCounter('','some_quick_counter', 'just a quick measurement')->inc()


Thanks! I'll check your suggestions ASAP!

I couldn't get everything working... More problems where on the Prometheus side integration... I did end up using phpredis instead of predis. Following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h75blZ3LgUk I have now a working integration... Thanks nonetheless, your answer was correct, but not enough for my setup to fully work...
